# BindingSource with DataTable in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

**Preamble:**
Having not worked with WinForms for a long while and also never before in VB I am trying to add a `DataGridView` to an application written in VB which will display a grid of data from a `DataTable`.

I followed the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) and in a simple test example I have the code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private count As Integer

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        count = count + 1

        Dim table As DataTable = BindingSource2.DataSource

        Dim row As DataRow
        row = table.NewRow()
        row("Col1") = "foo" + count.ToString()
        row("Col2") = "bar" + count.ToString()

        table.Rows.Add(row) 'throws System.InvalidOperationException here

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'BindingSource2.DataSource = New DataTable()
        'Dim table As DataTable = BindingSource2.DataSource
        Dim table As New DataTable

        Dim column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
        column1.ColumnName = "Col1"
        column1.Caption = column1.ColumnName
        column1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        table.Columns.Add(column1)

        Dim column2 As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
        column2.ColumnName = "Col2"
        column2.Caption = column2.ColumnName
        column2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        table.Columns.Add(column2)

        'Dim keys(0) As DataColumn
        'keys(0) = column1
        'table.PrimaryKey = keys

        ' first row
        Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
        row("Col1") = "beep"
        row("Col2") = "boop"

        table.Rows.Add(row)

        BindingSource2.DataSource = table
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code gets through `Form1_Load` okay however the entries added there are not shown in the `DataGridView`. Then when `Timer1_Tick` is called it throws a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception at the line indicated above. I cannot see what I am doing wrong based on the examples given in the docs.

**Question:** Can anybody help please, with (a) why does the `DataGridView` not reflect the added data at the end of `Form1_Load` and (b) why is adding a row causing an exception?

**P.s.** I've checked the debug and at the `table.Rows.Add(row)` `table` contains the correct information as does `row`.

**Edit:** The BindingSource was added and connected to the DataGridView using the designer so the code for it is shown instead in From1.Designer.vb which I haven't shown here.

Comment: You should replace `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` by `GetType(String)`. It’s more concise, and uses strong typing.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it but it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (at least in my case here) was that the `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` is not shown in the design panel and is by default set to `False`. I simply added the line

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

to my code (in `Form1_Load`) and it worked perfectly. I found the solution on a forum but now cannot find the link. I'll add it if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what to say. I used your code exactly and there's no exception happening. It works just fine. What I guess could be the problem is maybe the Timer1.Interval could be too low a value in conjunction to how fast the machine you are running the code on is. What if you increase the interval?

As for the data not being displayed ... add two columns to the DataGridView set the DataPropertyName property of each DataGridView column to match with each of the names of the table's column (in the Edit Colums... dialog). Then you'll get your data displayed.